# Receive a pass a object by reference using ctypes

Tags: python, c, ctypes

I have a library in C that has an object `IedConnection` that handles the connection to a remote equipment.

```
IedConnection con = IedConnection_create();
IedConnection_connect(con, &error, hostname, tcpPort);
IedConnection_destroy(con);
```

I understand how to pass and return `ctype` objects like `c_int`, but how would I declare the `IedConnection con` object in python using `ctypes`?

Comment: 1. there is no pass by reference in C. 2. You need to figure out the *actual* type of IedConnection - a pointer, struct, union, typedef alias for a scalar type or which it is... then it will be pretty much self-evident. The excerpt you've provided does not tell.

Comment: Is it this one? https://support.mz-automation.de/doc/libiec61850/c/latest/group__IEC61850__CLIENT__GENERAL.html

Comment: Yes, the library uses SWIG, but have a problem. I'm trying to make a wrapper using ctypes.  IedConnection is a struct. Is there a way to pass only the address of the object instead of building the whole struct in pyhton? @AnttiHaapala

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`IedConnection`](https://support.mz-automation.de/doc/libiec61850/c/latest/group__IEC61850__CLIENT__GENERAL.html) is a pointer to a structure (`typedef struct sIedConnection * IedConnection`). All pointers to structures should have the same representation, so you can just use a pointer to *any* structure, and need not define its contents, unless you want to dereference it or do pointer arithmetic. Hence this should work:

```
from ctypes import *

class SIedConnection(Structure):
    pass

IedConnection = POINTER(SIedConnection)
```

now you can use `IedConnection` as the [return type](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#return-types) and in the [argument types](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#specifying-the-required-argument-types-function-prototypes) as usual.